# get getAttribute src from iframe by getElementsByClassName not working php domdocument

Tags: php, iframe, domdocument, getelementsbyclassname

(There would be other iframes in the html so I am trying to call them by classname)

I tried:

```
$html = "<iframe width='100%' height='600' class='report' id='CReport' src='  http://www.example.com' ></iframe>";

$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($html);

$tags = $doc->getElementsByClassName('report');
$url = $tags->getAttribute('src');
echo $url;
```

Comment: anyone?  tried many things

Answer (score 0):

Try using below code:

```
<?php $tags = $doc->getElementById('CReport'); ?>
```